# Drupal 8 - How to print term description in twig

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to print a term description on the page--taxonomy--term.html.twig. The output of the term title works great `{{ page['#title'] }}`, but `{{ page['#description'] }}` does not working...

Please, help!

Comment: can you post the full content to your template here?

Comment: First check you have this key/value or not (use `{{ dump() }}`). and show me result (screen)

Comment: The problem is solved through the custom field in the taxonomy. Thanks to all who responded.